# Kubernetes: Local storage multiple nodes

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, storage, kubectl

In my kubernetes cluster, have 1 master and 3 nodes.

Will have a deployment/daemonset running on each node and will need storage.

Thought about local storage due performance issues with gluster, since will have a lot of files (small/big).

Is there a way of assigning automatically the pvc which has the pv in the node where the pod has been allocated?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can get  similar information to solve your issue [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/)

Comment: Hey @Bruno, Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of assigning automatically the pvc which has the pv in
> the node where the pod has been allocated?

It depends what you exactly mean by *"assigning automatically the pvc"* but I believe that [local volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) should meet your requirements. `PVC` or many different `PVCs`

It's biggest advantagle over `hostPath` is no need for scheduling Pods manually to specific nodes as node affinity is defined on the `PersistentVolume`:

> Compared to `hostPath` volumes, local volumes can be used in a durable
> and portable manner without manually scheduling Pods to nodes, as the
> system is aware of the volume's node constraints by looking at the
> node affinity on the PersistentVolume.

You just need to define a local storage class, local `PV` and `PVC`, which then you can use in `volumeClaimTemplates` like in the following fragment of a `Statefulset` specification:

```
...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: local-vol
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "local-storage"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 368Gi
```

All your `Pods` will be automatically scheduled to appropriate nodes as the node affinity is already defined in `PersistentVolume` and specific `PersistentVolumeClaim` is bind to such `PV`. It's important to remember that `PV:PVC` is always `1:1` binding, while one `PVC` can be used by many different `Pods`. When it comes to local volume, if `Pods` use a single common `PVC`, they all will be scheduled on the same node on which the claimed `PV` is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which nodes' PV's bind to which PVCs using `nodeAffinity`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#node-affinity

Claims can also specify a selector which will limit the pool of PVs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#selector